# Flyway and Spring

Tags: java, spring, flyway

I am trying to add Flyway to an existing Spring project. The question of this integration has been covered before, including in stackoverflow, but the articles/answers seem either old or about Spring Boot, which I **don't** use. Unless you suggest otherwise, I was planning on using the latest version to date (6.2.1).

I'm specifically looking for how to do the database migration with flyway.

Apart from adding the dependency, I've seen (in old questions) that I need to do something like this:

```
<bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate" depends-on="dataSource">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

However the package seems to have changed, and so as the property. Moreover, do I need to do anything else than that?

Can someone please tell me how to do it, or point me to an existing resource ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure it's not just about adding a line in your maven/gradle, you also need some spring configuration, which is what I'm looking for. And I don't understand why it's too broad, I'm just asking about how to ask flyway to migrate my database. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: I know that the scripts need to be put in /db/migration. But I'm looking for the integration with Spring (hence the title of my question). In other words, how do you make sure flyway actually runs and performs the migrations?

Comment: In the project you linked, you're using Spring Boot, and I specifically said in my original question that I don't use that, so I think I need to do the wiring on my own. This is the subject of my question. How to integrate flyway with a Spring project.

Comment: The person that was talking to me removed their comments, which leaves mine that make no sense :(. I'm still looking for help on this though, can someone please help me ?